# Apply same delimiter to all files

Tags: files

I have several files in different sub-directories. Some of them have a tab delimiter with just one 'tab character', as follow:

```
1971 1 1 120
1971 1 2 148
1971 1 3 159,5
...
```

And other ones have a tab delimiter with 7 'tab characters', as follow:

```
1971       1       1       120
1971       1       2       148
...
```

Is there a way to apply the same one 'tab' delimiter to all files of all sub directories?

Comment: Do files contain numbers only ? is there any text in them ?

Comment: @ Serg - It´s just about numbers!

Comment: cool. Working on an answer, will post soon

Comment: Would it be safe to rename *any* file containing a tab in the subdirectories's parent directory or are there files that should be excluded? if so based on which criterium should files be included / excluded?

Comment: @ kos - No files need to be excluded, I just want the same tab (1 tab character) for all the files. All sub-directories have the same kind of table files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find` + `rename`:

```
find . -type f -exec rename -n 's/\t{2,}/\t/g' {} \;
```

- `find`: searches a directory hierarchy
- `.`: searches the current working directory
- `-type f`: searches only files
- `-exec [...] {} [...] \;`: executes a command on each result;
- `rename`: renames files or directories
- `-n`: performs a dry run
- `s/\t{2,}/\t/g`: replaces any number of occurences of 2 or more tabulations with a single tabulation;

If the result is the expected one, remove the `-n` option.

Sample output (`\011` = `\t`):

```
% tree                                             
.
├── 1
│   ├── 1\0111\011\0111
│   ├── 1\0111\011\0112
│   ├── 1\0111\011\0113
│   ├── 1\0112\011\0111
│   ├── 1\0112\011\0112
│   ├── 1\0112\011\0113
│   ├── 1\0113\011\0111
│   ├── 1\0113\011\0112
│   └── 1\0113\011\0113
├── 2
│   ├── 2\0111\011\0111
│   ├── 2\0111\011\0112
│   ├── 2\0111\011\0113
│   ├── 2\0112\011\0111
│   ├── 2\0112\011\0112
│   ├── 2\0112\011\0113
│   ├── 2\0113\011\0111
│   ├── 2\0113\011\0112
│   └── 2\0113\011\0113
└── 3
    ├── 3\0111\011\0111
    ├── 3\0111\011\0112
    ├── 3\0111\011\0113
    ├── 3\0112\011\0111
    ├── 3\0112\011\0112
    ├── 3\0112\011\0113
    ├── 3\0113\011\0111
    ├── 3\0113\011\0112
    └── 3\0113\011\0113

3 directories, 27 files
% find . -type f -exec rename 's/\t{2,}/\t/g' {} \; 
% tree
.
├── 1
│   ├── 1\0111\0111
│   ├── 1\0111\0112
│   ├── 1\0111\0113
│   ├── 1\0112\0111
│   ├── 1\0112\0112
│   ├── 1\0112\0113
│   ├── 1\0113\0111
│   ├── 1\0113\0112
│   └── 1\0113\0113
├── 2
│   ├── 2\0111\0111
│   ├── 2\0111\0112
│   ├── 2\0111\0113
│   ├── 2\0112\0111
│   ├── 2\0112\0112
│   ├── 2\0112\0113
│   ├── 2\0113\0111
│   ├── 2\0113\0112
│   └── 2\0113\0113
└── 3
    ├── 3\0111\0111
    ├── 3\0111\0112
    ├── 3\0111\0113
    ├── 3\0112\0111
    ├── 3\0112\0112
    ├── 3\0112\0113
    ├── 3\0113\0111
    ├── 3\0113\0112
    └── 3\0113\0113

3 directories, 27 files
```